# How can I exit a Spring Camel application when no messages are received at an endpoint for x seconds

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to configure a standalone spring-camel application so that there is a route, and if no messages are received on that route for x seconds, the whole context will shutdown.

Let's say x is 10, if no message is received for 8 seconds, but then one arrives on the route, the counter should reset to 10 seconds. Once the counter reaches 0, the whole app should exit (gracefully, finishing whatever routes are currently processing)

If messages keep coming within the 10 seconds, the app should never exit.

Does anyone know an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe look at a Routepolicy...

Comment: I have looked at route policies as well as stopping and starting shutdown routes from within the main route. The problem I have is how to access and reset the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use latest Camel release 2.19.1, you can then configure it to terminate after X messages, X time, or being idle for more than X seconds.

You can find the options in the camel spring configuration, which you can configure in `application.properties` for Spring, such as

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelConfigurationProperties.java#L179

https://github.com/davsclaus/camel-profile-sample/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties#L24